# Fill textbox based on criteria from multiple comboboxes, MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm sure there is a simple answer here and yet hours of research to no avail:

I've a table called "Inventory" with fields "Materials," "Specification/Type", and "Description"

I've a form where there are comboboxes "Materials", "Spec", and a textbox "txtDesc"

I would like the text in txtDesc to show the corresponding description from the Inventory table when a user has made choices in the Materials and Spec comboboxes.

VBA version:

```
Private Sub Spec_AfterUpdate()
Me.txtDesc.Value = DLookup(“Description”, ”Inventory”, ”[Inventory].[Materials]= '" & Me.Materials.Value & "' AND [Inventory].[Specification/Type]= '" & Me.Spec.Value & "' ")
```

End Sub

SQL Version: (which I tried putting in the "control source" box in the textbox format)

```
SELECT [Description] FROM [Inventory] WHERE [Inventory].[Materials] = [Me.Materials] AND [Inventory].[Specification/Type] = [Me.Specification/Type]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the text box 'txtDesc' to a list box.

Then onclick in the second combobox (to gather all the required info), create your sql query and run it via

```
Me!textDesc.RowSource = SQL
Me!textDesc.Requery
```